# If $\phi\psi=id$, then $\phi$ is surjective and $\psi$ is injective

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations

The complete context of the question is the following. Suppose I have $End(V)$, which is the $K$-algebra of all endomorphisms of a vector space $V$ over a field $K$ with function composition as the bilinear map. Let $\phi \in End(V)$ be a unit of $End(V)$, thus there is some $\psi \in End(V)$ such that $\phi\psi=\psi\phi=id$. What I want to prove is that $\phi$ is surjective and $\psi$ is injective.

Here's what I have so far, I just want to make sure it is a proper proof since I feel like I'm missing something. To prove that $\phi$ is surjective, since $\phi\psi=id$, then $\phi(\psi(\mathbf{v}))=\psi(\mathbf{v})$, for some $\mathbf{v} \in V$. The identity map is surjective, and so $\phi$ is surjective. I'm not quite sure this is correct since it feels like I am saying that $\phi$ is the identity map, which it obviously doesn't have to be. But my understanding of $\phi\psi=id$ is that $\phi$ is just mapping its argument to itself, so it acts as the identity mapping. Someone correct me if this isn't the proper way of interpreting this.

To prove that $\psi$ is injective, suppose $\psi(\mathbf{v}_{1})=\psi(\mathbf{v}_{2})$. Then $\phi(\psi(\mathbf{v}_{1}))=\phi(\psi(\mathbf{v}_{2}))$. Based on other answers here, I should show that $\phi\psi$ is injective so then $\mathbf{v}_{1}=\mathbf{v}_{2}$ and thus prove that $\psi$ is injective. However, I am not sure how to prove that $\phi\psi$ is injective. Would I use the fact that $\phi\psi$ is the identity map and the fact that the identity map is injective? But again, that would rely on whether I am correct in my interpretation of $\phi\psi=id$.

Is this proof correct or is there something I am doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to Z$ be functions. Suppose $g\circ f$ is surjective.

We shall prove that $g$ is also surjective.

Indeed, it always holds that $g(Y)\subseteq Z$. We need to prove that $Z\subseteq g(Y)$:
\begin{align*}
Z = (g\circ f)(X) = g(f(X)) \subseteq g(Y)
\end{align*}
because $f(X)\subseteq Y$, and we are done!

Answer (score 0):

Meditate on the following. If we compose a non-injective function with any function at all, the result is not injective. If we precompose a non-surjective function with any function at all, the result is not surjective.

Answer (score 0):

Over here, when they write $\phi \psi$, what they really mean is $\phi \circ \psi$. So:
$$\forall v \in V: (\phi \circ \psi)(v) = \phi(\psi(v))$$

Your proof for surjectivity doesn't work. So, you know that $\phi \psi = id$. But this doesn't imply that $\phi(\psi(v)) = \psi(v)$ for every $v \in V$. To prove this, let $v \in V$. We want to show that there is a $w \in V$ such that $\phi(w) = v$. But now, you know that $\phi(\psi(v)) = v$. So, if we choose $\psi(v) = w$, then we're done. That proves surjectivity. Your proof for injectivity is correct and you know that $\phi \psi$ is injective precisely because it is the identity function and the identity function is injective.